# Unable to launch IE browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-iedriver

I have written a sample code to launch `IE browser` and load google page.

```
public class Sample {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","H:/IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  }
}
```

But when I run this script it launches browser and it gets closed immediately (less than 2 sec) without prompting any error and the script wont terminates.

This is what I can see on console screen:

> Started `InternetExplorerDriver` server (32-bit)
>
> 2.53.1.0
>
> Listening on port 46974
>
> Only local connections are allowed

Can any one help me on this issue?

Comment: is provided driver is latest???

Comment: Yes its IEDriver 2.53.1

Answer (score 2):

Below steps are worked for me, Hope this will work for you as well:

1. Open internet explorer.
2. Navigate to Tools->Option
3. Navigate to Security Tab
4. Now for all option like Internet,Intranet,Trusted Sites and
   Restricted Site enable "Enable Protected" mode check-box.
5. Set IE zoom level to 100%
6. Click on Apply and OK
7. Close the IE browser and run your script

Comment: Check the IE driver path you are providing, `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","H:\\IEDriverServer.exe");`

Answer (score 2):

To execute your code in IE need to set some security setting for your browser:
1) open IE
   Goto tools-- select internet options-- select security
   Set all zones (Internet , local internet,Trusted sites,Restricted sites) to the same protected mode(enabled or disabled is no matter)
2) set the zoom to 100% : In iE browser at top right hand side corner select settings symbol. select zoom . set zoom to 100% (what ever you want like 125,200 etc) close IE. 
3) If you want to see the zoom to display on the page:
   On the top right hand side of the browser just right click you will get some options , enable the status bar. Then you will be able to see the zoom at the rightside bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
       string path = @"H:\IEDriverServer.exe";
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(path);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.manage().window().maximize();

       driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: try to catch the exception

Comment: Leon, the code which I posted above works fine in my colleagues system and even it works in my system when I run it on IE8 but its not working when I run it on IE11.

Answer (score 0):

If your `IE` version is **11**, There are following steps to resolve it :-

- Registry entries for 32 and 64 bit.

create a **DWORD** value with the name **"iexplore.exe"** and the
value of 0 in the following key

```
for 32-bit Windows :- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE

for 64-bit Windows :- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

- Adjusted "Protected Mode" to be the same for all security zones by navigating through **Settings -> Internet Options -> Security**
- Unchek "Enable Protected Mode" for all zones
- Even rebooted.

If still getting the problem **Add domain to list of "Trusted Sites" for i.e. in "Internet Options" (https to trusted sites, and http to local intranet)**.

Hope it will help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
package tests;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Automation Workspace\\ComplianceDashboardProject\\Vendor\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

I did the above and got it to work.  Maybe try moving your driver file to another location to make sure there isn't some security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with sandeep's solution along with that for setting zoom level to 100% permanently i am adding few code lines as i faced issue to set this.

These are  the code lines i found after i browsed for the zoom level 100% error:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);           
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

For the security settings to execute code through IE : follow the steps in this link.`
'http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-ie-browser'

Hope this solution helps you.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Disabled JavaScript on IE can cause the test to not run.

I keep reading answers to set security setting to anything as long as it's consistent, but I find it's best to set them all to Medium, as this security level won't disable JavaScript. But in any case, if one has this issue, he can choose "Custom level..." for the "Internet" option in the Security tab, and make sure that "Active Scripting" under "Scripting" is *enabled*.

Of course, first make sure to complete all the steps in the [IEDriver docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).