# Unable to launch IE 11 when running selenium with IEDriverServer 3.9.0.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, iedriverserver

I'm having issues launching IE 11 when I run my selenium tests. Here is the code I am using to setup my browser

```
 if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",  "IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(800,600);
    driver.manage().window().setSize(dimension);
}
```

I tried the other solutions base off this thread but still no luck. [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222259/unable-to-launch-ie-browser-in-selenium-webdriver). Is there any solutions I can use?

Environment:

Selenium version: 3.12.0

IEDriverServer version: 3.9.0.0

IE Version: 11.0.65

Console output:

```
 Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
 3.9.0.0
 Listening on port 10696
 Only local connections are allowed
```

stack trace:

```
  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: 
  Connection reset
  Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-      08T14:04:26.12Z'
  System info: host: 'DESKTOP7', ip: '', os.name: '      Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
  Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:223)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:152)
at com.dlp.tests.TestCases.Basic_Template.setup(Basic_Template.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:212)
at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
```

Comment: I doubt this is an exception. This stack trace points to normal execution!

Comment: @Nilesh opps your right.

Comment: IMO, there is an issue, keeping my fingers crossed :|

Comment: @DebanjanB what kind of issue are you talking about?

Comment: @kav This question was raised by you. You have tell us about the issue you are facing

Comment: @DebanjanB I am having issues launching IE11 when I run my selenium test cases. I provided my source code and environment versions of how I am setting up my environment.

Comment: @kav As Nilesh mentioned _stack trace points to normal execution_, so where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: @DebanjanB Added the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.12.0** of **2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z** which is almost an year older.
- Your *InternetExplorerDriver* version **3.9.0.0**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.12.0* and *InternetExplorerDriver v3.9.0.0*. As per *best practices* as *Selenium Client* and *InternetExplorerDriver* are released in sync you must use both the binaries from the **same major release**.

---

Further **InternetExplorerDriver server v3.9.0.0** had a known issue as per the following references:

- [Can't launch Selenium IE Driver after upgrading to version 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895895/cant-launch-selenium-ie-driver-after-upgrading-to-version-3-9/48899810#48899810)
- [Selenium Java Client (v3.9.1) with IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0 (64-bit) crashes with org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28286](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5519)

This issue have been addressed through the following commit:

- [Properly initializing JSON values in IE driver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/13d8f8be751001d44df8e5f1797518f4fb4dec6b)

### Solution

- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to  current [**IEDriverServer v3.12.0**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IE was able to launch but it launches this URL `http://localhost:12303/` instead of going to the URL I provided and fails the test case. Would you whats causing this issue? I updated my post with the latest stack trace and code.

Comment: @DebanjanB can you stop posting arbitrary troubleshooting tips in your answers?  Making suggestions like "reboot" or "run ccleaner" just devalues your answers, and is not at all related to the question asked.